# MUI-RTE Getting the input content as string with HTML tags

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, rte

I have react based app with mui components and in this particular case I'm stuck on RTE.
The flow is:

- First, I get string like this one: `'<h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1><p>this is test</p>'`
  I format it with draft-js and put it inside MUI-RTE as defaultValue, all good, it shows up with all the stylings.
- Second, I want onSave/onChange to take the content of the MUI-RTE and save it with the new changes (doesn't matter what they are), in the format i've recieved them e.g. `'<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1><p>Updated Content</p>'`

The problem is i can't figure out how to get the content of the RTE like string with all the tags inside of it, it always turns up with some strange response and i can't parse it or stringify it properly...

```
  const sample = '<h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1><p>this is test</p>';
  const contentHTML = convertFromHTML(sample);
  const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
    contentHTML.contentBlocks,
    contentHTML.entityMap,
  );
  const content = JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(state));

  <MUIRichTextEditor
    label=""
    defaultValue={content}
    //onSave={}
    // or
    //onChange={}
  />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using [draft-js-export-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-export-html) it has worked for me

```
import { stateToHTML } from 'draft-js-export-html';

return ( 
 <YourComp 
   onChange={ value => stateToHTML(value.getCurrentContent()) }
  />
)
```